# ANR come when move other activity?

Tags: android

there is ANR problem comes when  we click gridView Item.My code is here..

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
    setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);
    setTheValue();
    roll_dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainScreen.this);
    roll_dialog.setMessage(" please wait while loading............");
    roll_dialog.show(); 
    startservice();


    // Getting Current Location 
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, mlocListener);

    profile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainScreen.this,MyProfile.class);
            intent.putExtra("lat", latLoc);
            intent.putExtra("long", longLoc);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    message.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {   

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(ChatScreen.kvp.size()!=0)
            {

                Intent intent=new Intent(MainScreen.this,GetOfflineMessages.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                showDialog(1);
            }
        }
    });

    chatroom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            showDialog(3);
        }
    });

    if(nearBySelected.equals("NearBy"))
    {
        nearBySelected="";
        roll_dialog.setMessage(" please wait while loading............");
        roll_dialog.show(); 
        new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Looper.prepare();
                getUsers("NEARBY");
            }
        }.start();
    }
    else //if(Near.equals("1")|| Near.equals(""))
    {
        new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                getUsers("");
            }
        }.start();  
    }

    checkInBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {



                 Bundle mbundle = new Bundle();
                   Intent mintent =new Intent(MainScreen.this, CheckInScreen.class);

                    mbundle.putDouble("lat", latLoc);
                    mbundle.putDouble("langit", longLoc);
                    mbundle.putString("userId", prefName);
                    mintent.putExtras(mbundle);
                startActivity(mintent);



        }
    });

    adMob.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(MainScreen.this, AdMobScreen.class));
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    Near="";
    Far="";
    // do my stuff
    Log.e("resumed","wassup");
    if(ChatScreen.kvp.size()!=0)
    {

        message.setText(""+ChatScreen.kvp.size());
    }
} 

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        timer.cancel();
      new WebServiceCallTask().execute();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
      super.onRestart();

         }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    //goOffline();
}

public void goOffline()
{
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",
            MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String prefName = myPrefs.getString(MY_ID, "0");

    String url = "http://dotnet4.peaceofmind.in/ms/ChestMeetAndMeet/ChestMeetAndMeatServices.asmx/GetUserListSpecificUser";
    Log.e("url", "" + url);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid",""+prefName));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("onlinestatus","false"));
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

                              /*it is main web services all app running from here*/
public void getUsers(final String getNearBy)
{
    String flag="";     
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    Location location = null, gps_loc;
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
     prefName = myPrefs.getString(MY_ID, "0");


    if(getNearBy.equalsIgnoreCase("NEARBY"))
     {

        try 
        {
            //mapController = mapView.getController();
            myLocation = new MyLocation()
            {
                public void locationClick() 
                {
                    myLocation.getLocation(MainScreen.this, locationResult);
                }

                LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void gotLocation(final Location location)
                    {
                        if(location != null)
                        {                           
                            neabylatitude = location.getLatitude();//*1E6
                            nearbylongitute = location.getLongitude();//*1E6
                             origin1 = Double.toString(neabylatitude);
                             origin2=  Double.toString(nearbylongitute);
                            url="http://dotnet4.peaceofmind.in/ms/ChestMeetAndMeet/ChestMeetAndMeatServices.asmx/UserListNearByWithSpecificUserId?sLatitude="+neabylatitude+"&sLongitude="+nearbylongitute+"&iRadius=10"+"&userid="+prefName;
                            System.out.println("near url"+url);
                            if(getNearBy.equalsIgnoreCase("NEARBY"))
                                 handelLocation("NEARBY");
                        }
                    }
                };
            };

            myLocation.locationClick(); 
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }
    }
    else
        handelLocation(getNearBy);

}

private void handelLocation(String getNearBy)
{
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    if(getNearBy.equalsIgnoreCase("FRIEND"))
    {
        url="http://dotnet4.peaceofmind.in/ms/ChestMeetAndMeet/ChestMeetAndMeatServices.asmx/GetUserFriendList?sUserId="+prefName;  
    }
    if(!getNearBy.equalsIgnoreCase("NEARBY") && !getNearBy.equalsIgnoreCase("FRIEND"))
    {
        url="http://dotnet4.peaceofmind.in/ms/ChestMeetAndMeet/ChestMeetAndMeatServices.asmx/GetUserListSpecificUser?userid="+prefName+"&onlinestatus=true";
    }
    try
    {
        int i;
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        URL url1= new URL(url);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //HttpEntity entity;
        HttpGet method= new HttpGet();
        method.setURI(new URI(url));

        //HttpRequest request=new           
        HttpResponse response=client.execute(method);           
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();         
        InputStream stream=entity.getContent();

        //InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());
        Log.e("b4 execute in login","aditya");


        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser(); 
        //   Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created.  
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader(); 
        //   Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader 
        //UserListHandler myExampleHandler = new UserListHandler(); 
        MainScreenHandler myExampleHandler = new MainScreenHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler); 
        //  Parse the xml-data from our URL.  
        xr.parse(new InputSource(stream)); 
        //  Parsing has finished.  

        ArrayList<MainScreenObject>  nearByArray = myExampleHandler.getnearbydicSearch();
        msg.obj = nearByArray;
        msg.arg1 = SUCCESS;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        msg.arg1 = FAILURE;
        Log.e("inside catch","io exception"+e.getStackTrace());     
        Log.e("inside catch","io exception"+e.getMessage());        
    }

    handler.sendMessage(msg);
}

//recieve Message here
public void receiveMessage()
{
    Message msg = receivedhandler.obtainMessage();
    String flag="";
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String prefName = myPrefs.getString(MY_ID, "0");
    Log.e("getlogin id ","1:"+prefName);

    String url="http://dotnet4.peaceofmind.in/ms/ChestMeetAndMeet/ChestMeetAndMeatServices.asmx/ReceiveMessage?iReceiverId="+prefName;

    try
    {
        Log.d("url","1"+url);
        int i;
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        URL url1= new URL(url);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet method= new HttpGet();
        method.setURI(new URI(url));

        //HttpRequest request=new 
        Log.e("b4 execute in login","1");
        HttpResponse response=client.execute(method);
        Log.e("b4 execute in login","2");
        HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
        Log.e("b4 execute in login","3");
        InputStream stream=entity.getContent();

        Log.e("b4 execute in login","3");
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser(); 

        //   Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created.  
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader(); 
        ReceiveMessageHandler myExampleHandler = new ReceiveMessageHandler(); 
        xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler); 
        xr.parse(new InputSource(stream)); 
        msg.arg1 = RECIEVESUCCESS;
        msg.obj = myExampleHandler.getReciveMessageList();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        msg.arg1=RECIEVEFAILURE;
        Log.e("inside catch","io exception");
    }   
    Log.d("getReturn",""+RegistrationSiteList.registrationResponse);
    //return flag;
    receivedhandler.sendMessage(msg);
}


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context mContext;
    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c,Activity a,String[] d) 
    {
        mContext = c;
        data=d;
        activity=a;
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(a);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() 
    {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return data[position];
    }


    public class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView name,onlinestatusgreen;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View vi=convertView;
        String onlinestauts ="";
        ViewHolder holder;
        String  Username="";
        if(convertView==null)
        {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loginstatus, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();

            holder.name=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.mainname);
            holder.name.setTextColor(R.color.black);

            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.onlinestatusgreen = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.onlinesataus);
            vi.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            vi.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            vi.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        if(userlist.size()>position)
        {
            String msgstatus = userlist.get(position).getMaritalStatus();
            String str ="1"+msgstatus;

            if(str.equals("1No Friend List Available"))
            {
                nofriendlistfound=true;
                onlinestauts ="1";

            }
            else
            {
                onlinestauts = userlist.get(position).getOnline();
                Username =userlist.get(position).getFirstName();
            }


        }
        holder.name.setText(Username);
        onlinestauts =onlinestauts+"1";

        if(onlinestauts.equalsIgnoreCase("true1"))
        {
            holder.onlinestatusgreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.onlinestatusgreen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }


        if(data.length!=0 && data[position]!=null  && !data[position].equals(""))
        {
            holder.image.setTag(data[position]);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position],MainScreen.this,holder.image);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        return vi;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.meat:
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            meat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.meat_h);


            Intent intent=new Intent(MainScreen.this,MeatAnimation.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        finish();   
        }

        else{
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                meat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.meat);
    }
        break;

    case R.id.mainglobal:
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            global.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.far_h);

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                roll_dialog.setMessage(" please wait while loading............");
                roll_dialog.show(); 
                new Thread()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        getUsers("");   
                    }
                }.start();


        }

        else{
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                global.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.far);
    }
        break;

    case R.id.friend:
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            friends.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.friends_h);
            SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",
                    MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            String prefName = myPrefs.getString(MY_ID, "0");
            if(prefName.equals("0"))
            {

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreen.this).create();
                alertDialog.setMessage("Please First make your account");
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                      // here you can add functions
                   }
                });
                //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
                alertDialog.show();
            }
            else
            {
                roll_dialog.setMessage(" please wait while loading............");
                roll_dialog.show(); 
                new Thread()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        Looper.prepare();
                        getUsers("FRIEND");
                    }
                }.start();  
            }
            }

            else{
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    friends.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.freinds);
        }

        break;

    case R.id.mainmrpec:
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            mrPec.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pec_h);

            Intent intent=new Intent(MainScreen.this,SendMail.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
            finish();
        }

        else{
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                mrPec.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pec);
    }
    break;
    case R.id.mainnearby:   
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        nearBy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.near_h);


            roll_dialog.setMessage(" please wait while loading............");
            roll_dialog.show(); 
            new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    getUsers("NEARBY");
                }
            }.start();
        }

        else{
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                nearBy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.near);
    }
    }
    return false;
    }


protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
   {        
    if(id == NO_NEW_MESSAGES)//Show message on Sign out button click.
    {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Sorry")
        .setMessage("No messages")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {

            }
        }
        )
        .create();
    }
    if(id ==3)
    {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("'Please buy our full version to unlock SCHNACK,\n undress all men,and help us \n with the cost,it's only 2$'")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {

            }
        }
        )
        .create();
    }
    if(id ==10)
    {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Please,First Create Profile")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {

            }
        }
        )
        .create();
    }
    if(id ==4)
    {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("No Friend List Available")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {

            }
        }
        )
        .create();
    }
    return null;
}



private void setTheValue()
  {
    meat=(Button)findViewById(R.id.meat);
    meat.setOnTouchListener(this);
    chatroom=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.chatroom);
    friends=(Button)findViewById(R.id.friend);
    friends.setOnTouchListener(this);
    profile=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile);
    nearBy=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mainnearby);
    nearBy.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mrPec=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mainmrpec);
    mrPec.setOnTouchListener(this);
    global=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mainglobal);
    global.setOnTouchListener(this);
    message=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.messages);      
    checkInBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.checkInBtn);
    adMob= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adMob);

}


private void startservice() 
{
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                    String prefName = myPrefs.getString(MY_ID, "0");
                    if(!prefName.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
                    {
                        receiveMessage();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
            Log.e("b4 setmessage","1:"+ChatScreen.kvp.size());

    }

    }, 0, INTERVAL);
}



public void getMeassageDetails()
{
    if(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.size()!=0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<objrReceiveMessageSiteList.size();i++)
        {
            KeyValuePair keysValues=new KeyValuePair();
            Log.e("added","2");
            keysValues.setLatitude(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getLatitude());
            keysValues.setLongitude(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getLongitude());
            keysValues.setSenderId(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getSenderId());
            keysValues.setMessageType(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getMessageType());
            keysValues.setMessage(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getMessage());
            keysValues.setTimeStamp(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getTimeStamp());
            keysValues.setSenderUserName(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getSenderUserName());
            keysValues.setSenderFirstName(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getSenderFirstName());
            ChatScreen.kvp.add(keysValues);
            Log.e("added","kvp size"+ChatScreen.kvp.size());
        }
        message.setText(""+ChatScreen.kvp.size());
    }   
}



public void showUsers()
{
    //site=new UserListSiteList();
    imageurl = new String[userlist.size()];//[(site.getProfileImage().size())];              
    int size=userlist.size();//site.getProfileImage().size();
    //Log.e("size",""+size);
    int matchUserId;
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) 
    {           
        imageurl[i] =userlist.get(i).getProfileImage(); ;//site.getProfileImage().get(i);
    } 

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,MainScreen.this,imageurl));


    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3)
        {
            String seletedmemberUserID="";
            String seletedmemberUserName="";
            String statusvalue="";
            if(userlist.size()>position)
            {
                 seletedmemberUserID = userlist.get(position).getUserId();
                 seletedmemberUserName = userlist.get(position).getFirstName();
                 statusvalue = userlist.get(position).getOnline();  
            }


            Bundle objbundle = new Bundle();
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainScreen.this,ProfileScreen.class);
            objbundle.putInt("position",position);
            objbundle.putString("selectuserid",seletedmemberUserID);
            objbundle.putString("selectusername",seletedmemberUserName);
            objbundle.putDouble("userlattiute",latLoc);
            objbundle.putDouble("userlongitute",longLoc);
            objbundle.putString("status",statusvalue);
            intent.putExtras(objbundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}



private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        String lat_long = loc.getLatitude() + "," + loc.getLongitude();


        lat_long =  "28.6146643,77.3714361";

        MyConstant.GlobalURL = MyConstant.CHECK_IN_URL+lat_long+"&radius=500&sensor=false&key=05qzDuEPI79pO6b_3kbDiikhFYO6uSQFo94qQpA";         

        latLoc=loc.getLatitude();
        longLoc=loc.getLongitude();

    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }       
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }       
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

}/* End of Class MyLocationListener */




class WebServiceCallTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
     private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainScreen.this);
    // can use UI thread here
      protected void onPreExecute() {

      }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        goOffline();
        return null;
    }

     // can use UI thread here
      protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {

      }
   }

private Handler handler = new Handler() 
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {

        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if(msg.arg1==SUCCESS)
        {
            roll_dialog.dismiss();
            userlist = (ArrayList<MainScreenObject>)msg.obj;
            String value = userlist.get(0).getMaritalStatus();
            String str="1"+value;
            showUsers();
            if(userlist.size()==0 || str.equalsIgnoreCase("1No Friend List Available"))
            {
                showDialog(4);
            }

        }
    }
};


private Handler receivedhandler = new Handler() 
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if(msg.arg1!=RECIEVEFAILURE)
        {
            objrReceiveMessageSiteList =(ArrayList<ReceiveMessageSiteList>)msg.obj;
            if(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.size()!=0)
            {

                for(int i=0;i<objrReceiveMessageSiteList.size();i++)
                {
                    KeyValuePair keysValues=new KeyValuePair();
                    Log.e("added","2");
                    keysValues.setLatitude(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getLatitude());
                    keysValues.setLongitude(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getLongitude());
                    keysValues.setSenderId(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getSenderId());
                    keysValues.setMessageType(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getMessageType());
                    keysValues.setMessage(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getMessage());
                    keysValues.setTimeStamp(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getTimeStamp());
                    keysValues.setSenderUserName(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getSenderUserName());
                    keysValues.setSenderFirstName(objrReceiveMessageSiteList.get(i).getSenderFirstName());
                    ChatScreen.kvp.add(keysValues);

                }
                message.setText(""+ChatScreen.kvp.size());
            }
        }


    }
};
```

I have already used AsyncTask instead of recieve handler which call by Timer 9in fixed interval.

Comment: Have you mentioned MyProfile activity in Manifest file of your project ?

Comment: hi thanks for reply,but only one sigle line shown in logcat..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be somewhere you are blocking the main UIThread or performing heavy operation without thread.
The heavy task without thread will may result into ANR

To know where the ANR can cause follow the steps as below

> 1) select android api level to 9
>
> 2) please the following lines in onCreate() just after setContentView()

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() 
    .penaltyLog().build());
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
    .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects().detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
    .penaltyLog().penaltyDeath().build());
```

> 3) Select Debug from the drop down of logcat

you will get the strict mode logs that refers to the place where you have to take action

Comment: put you heavy transaction like storing data on sdCard, creating files, using DB, network call, webservice call etc into thread and if you function does with change in any view then that thing must be done inside runOnUiThread() or create handler for that purpose. got my point